# Передача auto_ptr по ссылке

Tags: stl, указатели, c++

В книге Джосьютиса "Стандартная библиотека C++" написано, что нельзя передавать `auto_ptr` по ссылке, т.к. это, якобы, может привести к очень плохим результатам (нет никакой гарантии, что право владения объектом не передастся локальному параметру функции). Но вот что делаю я, и у меня все нормально:

```
std::auto_ptr<int> ptr1(new int(44));
std::auto_ptr<int> ptr2(ptr1);
{
    char buff[10];
    _itoa_s(*ptr2,buff,10,10);
    MessageBoxA(hWnd,buff,"My Value",NULL); //44
}

MyPrintBad(ptr2); //44

{
    char buff[10];
    _itoa_s(*ptr2,buff,10,10);
    MessageBoxA(hWnd,buff,"My Value",NULL); //44! no error
}
```

**MyPrintBad**:

```
void MyPrintBad( std::auto_ptr<int>& ptr)
{
    //std::auto_ptr<int> new_ptr(new int(45));
    //ptr = new_ptr;
    char buff[10];
    _itoa_s(*ptr,buff,10,10);
    MessageBoxA(NULL,buff,"MyPrintBad",NULL);
 }
```

Все работает нормально, указатель возвращается в нормальном состоянии из функции и никакого сбоя не происходит, при этом, ссылка даже не константная. **Вопрос**: так можно ли все-таки передавать *auto_ptr* по ссылке, если я хочу выполнить какие-то операции чтения данного объекта?

Comment: Интерес практический или теоретический? Если практический, то не используйте auto_ptr! Используйте другие, более надежные, умные указатели из Boost или С++11.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Если не учитывать закомментированный код, то вы **не делаете ничего опасного** (за исключением прямой передачи указателя, обернутого с помощью `std::auto_ptr,` но иногда без этого не обойтись).
- Если раскомментировать фрагмент кода с `ptr = new_ptr:`

> - Для этого варианта все "будет работать", поскольку с точки зрения работы с указателями, ваш метод `MyPrintBad` сводится к `ptr = std::auto_ptr<int>(new int(45));`
> - Это **нехороший** код, поскольку совершенно неочевидно, что метод `MyPrintBad` освободит прошлый участок памяти и подменит его каким-то новым.

- Если ради интереса предположить, что вы написали `"new_ptr = ptr",` а не `"ptr = new_ptr"` (а это, кстати, более интересный случай), то все [было бы плохо:](http://www.gotw.ca/publications/using_auto_ptr_effectively.htm)

> - To see why, first consider what happens when you copy an `auto_ptr`: An `auto_ptr` owns the object that it holds a pointer to, and only one `auto_ptr` may own an object at a time. When you copy an `auto_ptr`, you automatically transfer ownership from the source `auto_ptr` to the target `auto_ptr`; if the target `auto_ptr` already owns an object, that object is first freed.
> - After the copy, only the target `auto_ptr` owns the pointer and will delete it in due time, while the source **is set back to a `null` state** and can no longer be used to refer to the owned object.

- В этом случае вы передадите вашей функции `auto_ptr`, далее передадите право на освобождение объекта локально созданному `auto_ptr'у`, который освободит память при выходе из функции. А в `auto_ptr,` переданному по ссылке, будет висеть `null`.

> - То есть, до выхода из функции у вас в `ptr2` будет указатель на какую-то память, а после выхода из функции там будет `NULL,` а соответствующая память будет освобождена.
> - Это, конечно, может быть ожидаемым поведением, но в большинстве случаев бессмысленно, опасно и нелогично.

Comment: Прикол в том что если даже тот код разкомментить то все нормально работает.

Comment: @stremm Я почему-то захотел увидеть в вашем коде `new_ptr = ptr` и отвечал из этих соображений. Обновил ответ.

Answer (score 2):

Вы привели код хэлловорлда в котором 30 строк. В реальных проектах код объёмен, его модифицируют разные разработчики. Вы не будете читать каждую функцию перед тем как передать туда auto_ptr, чтобы быть уверенным что она ничего не меняет. Даже если и будете читать, то нет гарантии что Ваш коллега через год после Вашего увольнения не изменит функцию, и она будет делать присваивание.

Если нужно передавать, то передавайте голый указатель через `get()`

`MyFunction( ptr.get() )`

Comment: либо компилятор просто откажется компилировать подобный код. gcc 4.7 с параметром `-std=c++11` уже намекает, что лучше не использовать.

Comment: @KoVadim: http://ideone.com/c1j4q

Comment: и к чему этот код? мол gcc? тогда версию посмотрите.

Answer (score 1):

Тип `auto_ptr<T>` лучше вообще не использовать. Если есть хоть какой-то выбор, то нет ни одной причины для того, чтобы использовать именно его. Дело в том, что он ведёт себя совершенно противоестественно. Копирование объекта через конструктор и присваивание влекут за собой передачу владения указателем в копию. Оригинал же владеть указателем перестаёт. Приходится постоянно помнить о том, что очень легко забыть, поскольку это контринтуитивное поведение.

Но если уж использовать, то передавать его следует только по ссылке. В противном случае с указателем можно попрощаться. Если передать `auto_ptr<T>` в функцию без ссылки, то хранящийся в нём указатель попросту засосёт в функцию, и объект будет уничтожен после выхода из неё.